# PostgreSQL: Is there a practical limit of a table size for HASH index? (HASH index is unable to create but other indexes are within a minute)

Tags: postgresql, indexing, hash

I tried to create several types of indexes on same column of my table to see how they compare, all of them I was able to create quickly but not a HASH index. I read about them how they got better in recent Postgres versions but I guess they may still have some limitations.

My table has 96 477 996 rows and column I tried indexes on is type of integer.

```
CREATE INDEX gpps_brin_index ON cdc_s5_gpps_ind USING brin (id_transformace) WITH (pages_per_range='256');
--27s 879ms
-- drop index gpps_brin_index; 
CREATE INDEX gpps_gin_index ON cdc_s5_gpps_ind USING gin (id_transformace); 
-- 1m 13s
-- drop index gpps_gin_index;
CREATE INDEX gpps_btree_index ON cdc_s5_gpps_ind (id_transformace); 
-- 45s 744ms
-- drop index gpps_btree_index;
```

But hash index didn't finish even after 38 minutes

```
CREATE INDEX gpps_hash_index ON cdc_s5_gpps_ind USING hash (id_transformace);
```

I tried to set work memory to 4GB to see if it makes any difference but no change.

So if other indexes are created within a minute then there is probably something wrong with hash index. I tried to create it on some small table and it finished quickly so it seems there is probably some size limitations when from certain table size index will start to struggle. Can someone confirm me this or is there something I am missing.

**EDIT:** As explained by @jjanes I tried hash index on another column which has only unique values (row id) and HASH index was created in 2m34s.

> PostgreSQL 12.3 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 8.3.1
> 20191121 (Red Hat 8.3.1-5), 64-bit

Comment: Try increasing `maintenance_work_mem`, that will speed up index creation. But I wouldn't use has indexes at all, and I have not seen anybody else use them either.

Comment: `maintenance_work_mem` is already set to 2GB in our DB but I will give it a shot and set it to 8GB if it makes any change, ... I never used them too, but recently I read some articles how they got better in recent pg versions so I decided to gave them a try

Comment: They got crash safe, not necessarily better.

Comment: Main advantage they spoke about should be size reduction when HASH index would be around half of a Btree so not only taking less disk space but also easier fitting into cache

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe  They also got better in other ways, like using lighter weight locks so as to have less contention on high concurrency.  I don't know if the multi-reader contention is now better than btree, but at least it is not remarkably worse anymore.  I've used them a handful of times.  Not based on concurrency, but when I needed an index that would not fail if 0.00001% of rows had the indexed column longer than ~2730 bytes.

Comment: This report surprises me, I would not have predicted that off the top of my head.  Is the table vacuumed and analyzed before the index build is launched?  (Hash index builds like to know how many buckets to use from the start.)  How many distinct id_transformance are there?  Does each value of id_transformance have roughly the same number of rows, or are they greatly skewed?  Can you identify the table size at which the performance collapses?  Have you tried in 10 or 11 to see if this is a regression in 12?

Comment: @jjanes each id_transformace has approximately 1M rows, but they are batches so they are not evenly distributed, I only tried it so far on pg 12, I can try it on PG 11 to see if there is any difference, ... in my experience (and some people who knows postgres quite well told me the same) that postgres has problems with large hash tables, so maybe that could be the case here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say you have 100 distinct values, which occur about 1 million times each.  So only 100 buckets can ever be occupied. Once each id_transformance has its own bucket, then no matter how many more times you split a bucket, all the rows follow one path of the split and end up in the same bucket again.  So each occupied bucket will have a long list of overflow pages.  And I don't think there is a fast path to get to the end of such a list, you have to traverse it each time you need to add a record to the end.

So you get degenerate build performance when you have a large number of rows, but with only a small number of distinct values.  This is not a general problem with large tables, but is specific to this situation.

This could possibly be improved for bulk index creation by creating a fast-path to the end of the  overflow page list or the most-recently used bucket, but even if it were I still don't think this index type would be well suited for this type of data.

Comment: Well B-tree, GIN and BRIN indexes are doing just fine not only at building part but also with queries so I am not sure if what you wrote is meant as a general rule or some specific of a HASH index?

Comment: Splitting hash buckets and having overflow pages are specific to hash indexes.

Comment: Thank you it worked, I edited my post for results, interesting that I haven't seen anybody mentioning this in either documentation or in any articles where they were posting results for testing them.